# A Question in 1st order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I have a question when solving exercise from ODE by E.A.Coddington
page 42 Q8 as follows

consider the equation $ y'+ay=b(x )$, where a is a constant, and b is a continuous function on $o \le x <\infty $, satisfying there $|b(x)| \le k $, where k is some positive number.

(a) Find the solution satisfying y(0)=0

(b) If Re(a) $ \neq $ 0, Show that the solution satisfies $$|y(x)| \le \frac {k}{Re(a)} [1- e^{-(Re(a)x} ] $$

I am lost on how to prove part a as i have only one property about b.

please any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: There must be a typo, since the solution does not appear in the formula that the solution is supposed to satisfy. Should the left hand side be $|y(x)|$? – For part (a), let $u(x)=e^{ax}y(x)$ and find the ODE satisfied by $u$. (Also, please don't use the asterisk $*$ for multiplication. In mathematics, it stands for *convolution*.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen hi it is typo just corrected it thanks

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen i tried u r substitution dont see how it helps can you be more clear please thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a) – and this is standard textbook stuff, though it may be presented differently – if $u(x)=e^{ax}y(x)$ then you get $u'=e^{ax}(y'+ay)=e^{ax}b(x)$, leading to $u(x)=u(0)+\int_0^x e^{at}b(t)\,dt$. Substituting back, you get $$y(x)=y(0)e^{-ax}+\int_0^x e^{a(t-x)}b(t)\,dt=\int_0^x e^{a(t-x)}b(t)\,dt$$
(since $y(0)=0$).

For (b), the formula above gives
$$|y(x)|\le\int_0^x |e^{a(t-x)}b(t)|\,dt
  \le k\int_0^x|e^{a(t-x)}|\,dt.$$
Finally, for any complex $z$ use $|e^z|\le e^{\operatorname{Re}z}$ to estimate the integral. May I leave the last bit to you?

Comment: I am grateful to you thanks i keep forgetting for 1st order ode i should try this substitution even when you hinted i am finding hard to make connection with this i appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attack on this problem:

Starting with the given equation

$$y' + ay = b(x), \tag{1}$$

we follow the suggestion of Harald Hanche-Olsen's comment and set

$$u(x) = e^{ax}y(x). \tag{2}$$

It should be noted at this point that this is a well-known and standard approach to equations of the general form (1), and if you search the web for topics such as *integrating factors* and the *variation of parameters* method, you will quite likely find a panoply of references/citings to this technique.  In any event, making the substitution (2) we see that

$$u'(x) = ae^{ax}y(x) + e^{ax}y'(x) = e^{ax}(y'(x) + ay(x)), \tag{3}$$

leading to

$$u'(x) = e^{ax}(y'(x) + ay(x)) = e^{ax}b(x), \tag{4}$$

which may immediately integrated, yielding

$$u(x) - u(0) = \int_0^x e^{as}b(s)\, ds, \tag{5}$$

and since $u(0) = y(0) = 0$, $\text{(5)}$ becomes

$$u(x) = \int_0^x e^{as}b(s)\, ds, \tag{6}$$

or

$$e^{ax}y(x) = \int_0^x e^{as}b(s)\, ds, \tag{7}$$

or

$$y(x) = e^{-ax} \int_0^x e^{as}b(s) ds, \tag{8}$$

the sought solution for $y(x)$.  Here, two points are worthy of note:  first, this solution cannot be taken further without greater, specific information regarding $b(x)$; and second, the factor $e^{ax}$ is known as the *integrating factor* for (1), since its introduction *via* (2)-(4) allows the resulting equation to be integrated forthwith, as in (5).  In any event, having (8) in hand, we may proceed to estimate $\vert y(x) \vert$, as follows:  by (8),

$$\vert y(x) \vert = \vert e^{-ax} \int_0^x e^{as} b(s) ds \vert = \vert e^{-ax} \vert \vert \int_0^x e^{as}b(s) ds \vert \le \vert e^{-ax} \vert  \int_0^x \vert e^{as}\vert \vert b(s) \vert ds. \tag{9}$$

We look at the exponential factors occurring in (9):  we have, for any complex $a = Re(a) + i Im(a)$,

$$\vert e^{ax} \vert = \vert e^{Re(a) x} e^{i Im(a) x} \vert = \vert e^{Re(a) x} \vert \vert  e^{i Im(a) x} \vert = \vert e^{Re(a) x} \vert = e^{Re(a) x}, \tag{10}$$

since $\vert  e^{i Im(a) x} \vert = 1$ and $e^{Re(a) x} > 0$ for all real $x, Re(a), Im(a)$.  We thus have for the right-hand integral in (9), also using $\vert b(x) \vert \le k$:

$$\int_0^x \vert e^{as}\vert \vert b(s) \vert  \le k \int_0^x e^{Re(a) s} ds = (k / Re(a))[e^{Re(a) x} - 1]; \tag{11}$$

returning to (9), using (11),

$$\vert y(x) \vert \le \vert e^{-ax} \vert  \int_0^x \vert e^{as}\vert \vert b(s) \vert ds$
$\le e^{-Re (a) x} (k / Re(a))[e^{Re(a) x} - 1] = (k / Re(a))[1 - e^{-Re(a) x}], \tag{12}$$

which is the required estimate.

Hope this helps.  Happy New Year,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: @ Adobe:  Can't say I object to these particular edits of yours; they didn't effect the mathematical content.  But why is this (edited) version better?  At first glance, it looks the same to me.  Seriously, I am genuinely curious about what's going on here.  Am I missing some point of Latex I should know?

Comment: Thanks for the answer i already got it from Harald but appreciate the effort